# What classes of graphs result from $\overline{T}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I need help in characterizing the classes of graphs that results from taking the complementary of a tree, i.e., the graph that results from removing the edges of a tree from a complete graph. More formally, let $T=(V,E)$ be an $n$-vertex tree with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. Are there known results on the classes of graphs defined by $\overline{T}$?

There are two trivial cases. If $T=S_n$, i.e., is a star tree (one single vertex has degree $n-1$ and the other vertices have degree $1$), we have that $\overline{S_n}=\{v\}\cup K_{n-1}$, i.e., $\overline{S_n}$ is a graph with an isolate vertex (degree $0$) and a $(n-1)$-vertex clique. I've got the feeling that $\overline{P_n}$ (where $P_n$ is an $n$-vertex path graph) has a precise characterization but I can't put a name to it.

If there are no (or few) results about general $T$, can we say something about $\overline{T}$ if $T$ belongs to a class of trees, for example caterpillar trees (trees in which the removal of all leaves produces a path graph), lobster trees (trees in which the removal of all leaves produces a caterpillar tree), ...?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Note: I'm crossposting this from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4370420/746100).

Comment: MathWorld calls $\overline{P_n}$ a [path complement graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PathComplementGraph.html), which is probably less interesting than you were hoping.

Comment: Well, at least now I can put a name to it :). Thank you for the link!

Comment: In case $T$ is a spanning tree, its complement is sometimes called the "co-spanning tree" (which sounds odd because it need not be a tree), as I learned from this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77132/co-spanning-tree

Comment: Broadly speaking, a graph and its complement contain the same information, so "complements of trees" are probably not studied much because whatever you could say about them translates to a statement about trees.

Comment: The [Information System on Graph Classes and their Inclusions](https://www.graphclasses.org/) calls complements of [trees](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_342.html) [co-cycle-free](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_2103.html).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the webpage. These links are a must-to-have.